# Swift class as argument to objc runtime

Tags: swift, objective-c-runtime

When using the objc runtime for Swift introspection, I noted that the following is possible:

```
object_setClass(anObject, Birdy.classForCoder());
```

. . . but not

```
object_setClass(anObject, Birdy);
```

Both Birdy.classForCoder() and Birdy are an instance of AnyClass, so why is it that only the former will propagate into the objc runtime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Birdy.self` to get the `AnyClass` metatype.

Example:

```
object_setClass(anObject, Birdy.self)
```

If you plan on making your Swift classes available within Obj-C, you should mark them with the `@objc` annotation:

```
@objc class Birdy
{
    func tweet()
    {
        println("Tweet tweet! #swift")
    }
}
```